# Are these functions computable?

Tags: computability, halting-problem

consider $g$ and $f$ and $h$ as

$
\begin{align*}
g(m) &= 
   \begin{cases}
     1 & if\;program\;m\;halts\;on\;input\;m \\
     0 & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
f(m,n) &= 
   \begin{cases}
     undefined & if\;m=n \\
     1 & if\;program\;m\;halts\;on\;input\;n \\
     0 & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
h(m,n) &= 
   \begin{cases}
     1 & if\;program\;m\;halts\;on\;input\;n \\
     0 & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$

we have a counter example for computability of $g$ and $h$ but we don't have any counter example for $f$ and even more interesting function $f_{all}$
$$f(m,n)=\dfrac{m-n}{m-n}h(m,n)$$
$$f_{all}(m)=1-sgn(\lim_{w \to \infty}\sum_{\substack{n=0 \\ n\neq m}}^{w}(1-f(n,m)))$$

we know that if $p$ is a universal diophantine polynomial then we can represent a non-computable solution to the halting problem as follows
$$
h(m,n) = sgn(\lim_{w \to \infty}\sum_{x_1=1}^{w}...\sum_{x_u=1}^{w}\dfrac{1}{1 + wp^2(m,n,x_1,...,x_u)})
$$

now the question is: are $f$ and $f_{all}$ computable?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that $f$ is **not** computable, using the padding lemma: there is a total computable function $t$ such that for all $x$, $t(x)>x$ but program number $x$ and program number $t(x)$ have the same behavior (= yield the same partial computable function).

This means that $f$ computes $g$, since we have $g(x)=f(x,t(x))$.

Comment: For instance, informally, $t(x)$ can be obtained from $x$ by inserting a no-op instructions.  (I know that Turing machines don't have instructions, so make the corresponding translation to Turing machines.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139945/discussion-on-answer-by-noah-schweber-are-these-functions-computable).

Comment: I will accept your answer if you change $g(x) = f(x,t(x))$ to $g(x) = f(t(x),x)$